# API Integrator Keys button not show

Tags: docusignapi

I have purchase account of DocuSign.I want API interaction of DocuSign on my application but Integrator Keys generator button does not show my account.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ff8k.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly create Integrator Key in the DocuSign PROD environment. You need to create a developer Sandbox/Demo account [Developer Sandbox Account](https://secure.docusign.com/signup/develop), then create an Integrator Key in this account [Generate Integrator Key](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#integrator-key). And then develop your API integration application in this Sandbox account, once you are done with your development and testing then you need to go through API Go Live process [API Go Live process](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live) to promote your Sandbox Integrator Key to your PROD Account